# PHP: trying to redirect to specific url

Tags: php, redirect, woocommerce

i am using a code to redirect customers to a specific page after login. But i don't know how to enter a specifc url in php.

I want the customers to be redirected to [www.example.de/example/](http://www.example.de/example/) after login.

How can this be done? I think this can be done somehow with this and a path to follow:  *$myaccount =*  ?

This is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Redirect users to custom URL based on their role after login
 *
 * @param string $redirect
 * @param object $user
 * @return string
 */
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
    $role = $user->roles[0];

    $dashboard = admin_url();
    $myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );

    if( $role == 'administrator' ) {
        //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {
        //Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'editor' ) {
        //Redirect editors to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'author' ) {
        //Redirect authors to the dashboard
        $redirect = $dashboard;
    } elseif ( $role == 'customer' || $role == 'subscriber' ) {
        //Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
        $redirect = $myaccount;
    } else {
        //Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
        $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
    }

    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
?>
```

Thank you very mich in advance!

Best regards,
Phil

Answer (score 1):

Generally to redirect user to some url you can use `header()` function.
`header("location:http://www.example.de/example/")`
then you should write `exit();` after the header function to prevent the code below from excuting.
you need to also make sure that there are no other output sent before the header function.
you can read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)